# User-defined overloaded max function call giving error: "call of overloaded 'max<int>(int, int)' is ambiguous"

Tags: c++, function-templates-overloading

User-defined overloaded `max` function call gives error:

> call of overloaded 'max(int, int)' is ambiguous

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto max(T1 a, T2 b)
{
    return b<a?a:b;
}

template<typename RT, typename T1, typename T2>
RT max(T1 a, T2 b)
{
    return b<a?a:b;
}

int main() 
{
    auto rt = ::max(4,7);
    std::cout<<typeid(rt).name()<<std::endl;
    auto rrt = ::max<int>(4,7);
    std::cout<<typeid(rrt).name()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
/tmp/X2ZgbGkKk9.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/tmp/X2ZgbGkKk9.cpp:21:26: error: call of overloaded 'max<int>(int, int)' is ambiguous
   21 |     auto rrt = ::max<int>(4,7);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/tmp/X2ZgbGkKk9.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: 'auto max(T1, T2) [with T1 = int; T2 = int]'
    5 | auto max(T1 a, T2 b)
      |      ^~~
/tmp/X2ZgbGkKk9.cpp:11:4: note: candidate: 'RT max(T1, T2) [with RT = int; T1 = int; T2 = int]'
   11 | RT max(T1 a, T2 b)
```

If the template argument is set to `int` in the following line, the ambiguous error is thrown:

```cpp
auto rrt = ::max<int>(4,7);
```

***Whereas it works if the template argument is changed to `double`, i.e.***:

```cpp
auto rrt = ::max<double>(4,7);
```

I failed to understand the reason. Please help.

Comment: It IS ambiguous.  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Which overload do you expect `max<int>(4,7)` to use, and why? (Neither of your templates has only one template parameter, so I can't go by the fact that you supplied only one template argument.)

Comment: Both signatures match your usage so there is ambiguity here. Side note : also never put functions in the global namespace (certainly not functions called min/max)

Comment: @TimRoberts, why changing the template argument to double i.e. to ::max<double>(...) works but ::max<int>(...) doesn't work?

Comment: @SandeepNagar *"why changing the template argument to double i.e. to ::max<double>(...) works"* -- Try this experiment: `::max<double>(4.0,7)` (the template parameter is `double` and the first function parameter changed from `4` to `4.0`).

Answer (score 4):

When you don't provide template parameters, only the first overload is available because in the second overload the type `RT` is not deducible, so there is no ambiguity, and the call to `::max(4,7)` succeeds, calling the first overload, with both `T1` and `T2` deduced to `int`.

When you provide one template parameter, both overloads become available. The call `::max<int>(4,7)` can either call the first overload with `T1` explicitly set to `int` and `T2` deduced to be `int`, or call the second overload with `RT` explicitly set to `int` and both `T1` and `T2` deduced to be int. After substituting the types, the signatures of both overloads are `auto(int,int)` and `int(int,int)`. They are equally good in overload resolution and therefore ambiguity occurs.

When you do `::max<double>(4,7)`, again both overloads are available. Following the same logic, the signature of the two overloads would be `auto(double,int)` and `double(int,int)`. In this case, the first overload requires an additional conversion in the argument, and hence less favorable, and the second overload is unambiguously picked, hence no ambiguity arises.

You can read more about overload resolution [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function).

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer. It cleared my doubt.